# Can't make this work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can i change variable value?, i tried using "Promises" but it doesn't work it gaves me an error, i'm trying to load a data on a  table

```
                /* Formating function for row details */
                function fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr) {
                    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
                    var sOut ='';
                    $.post("http://localhost:3000/almuerzo/findIng", {
                            nombre: aData[1]},
                        function(data, status){
                            sOut = '<ul>';
                            sOut += data.nombre;
                            sOut += '</ul>';
                        });                    
                        return sOut;
                }
```

As i said when i try to use promises de "datable.tabletools plugin" fails, said that there's an error on "show"

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use

```
return sOut;
```

Outside the callback function.

sOut would always be '' in your example.

Comment: Anyidea of how can i make this work?

Comment: don't return from your callback. Just do whatever you need to do with sOut right from your callback.